# Square visible inside of Compose button bounds when add alpha to the button background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a button with a border of the color orange, and a background color of the color orange with an alpha of .5f. When adding the alpha using `ButtonDefaults.buttonColors`, a box of a different color appears in the background of the button.

Code:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun NextButtonPreview() {
    Button(
        enabled = true,
        onClick = {},
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, colorPrimaryDark),
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(all = 8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp)
            .testTag(GENERIC_NEXT_BUTTON_TEST_TAG),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = colorPrimaryDarkHalfOpactiy,
            contentColor = colorPrimary,
            disabledBackgroundColor = gray,
            disabledContentColor = colorPrimary
        )
    ) {
    }
}
```

Result:
Note the box rendered inside the button background

[image]

I have tried different color resources, removing the content of the button, and copying the color of applying an alpha to no avail. This issue persists regardless of the color used.

[Button at Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Okz.png)

Comment: Is this an issue only with the preview? I don't see any issue after running the app.

Comment: Add the values for all the colors used to look further into this

Comment: Sadly this is also an issue at runtime, added image showing the issue. colorPrimaryDark maps to Color(0xFFD15F27)

Answer (score 0):

The box rendered inside the button background represents the default content/child area of the button. It wont be reflected in the app it is just a preview thing showing the padding between the button and content.

Try adding a Box with a color as content to the button to visualise it

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green).fillMaxSize()){}
```

Note : The white part will become green since the Box fills the entire content area.

Comment: Sadly the box is rendered at runtime. See updated image in question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be coming from the elevation.
The darker "frame" part of the button is the shadow caused by the elevation that we can see through the transparently colored background.

If you remove the
`elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(8.dp)` you will see that the problem goes away.

You probably still want elevation, so I would find the color without any transparency that matches the color you want.

From your screenshot that would be something like
Color(0xFFDFA686)

**Update:**
My code keeping the elevation with a non-transparent background color:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun NextButtonPreview() {
    val colorPrimaryDark = Color(0xFFD15F27)
    val buttonColor = Color(0xFFDFA686)

    Button(
        enabled = true,
        onClick = {},
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, colorPrimaryDark),
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(all = 8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = buttonColor,
            contentColor = Color.Green,
            disabledBackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
            disabledContentColor = Color.Green
        )
    ) {}
}
```

The preview:
[image: preview]

Or removing the elevation but keeping the transparent background color:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun NextButtonPreview() {
    val colorPrimaryDark = Color(0xFFD15F27)
    val buttonColor = colorPrimaryDark.copy(alpha = 0.5f)

    Button(
        enabled = true,
        onClick = {},
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, colorPrimaryDark),
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(0.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(all = 8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = buttonColor,
            contentColor = Color.Green,
            disabledBackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
            disabledContentColor = Color.Green
        )
    ) {}
}
```

The preview:
[image]

Comment: Sorry about my slow response had to do some heads down coding. Unfortunately, neither removing button elevation nor changing the color spec have any impact on the visibility of the square; it is still visible. Does the default Material Theme define default alphas for text viability or anything?

Comment: @psmith updated my answer with code and previews. Both approaches seem to work for me.